# How To Link DevIL Linker Libraries Properly?

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, linker-errors, devil

Linking these libraries was just like linking any other library.

But my issue comes when I run my project I am not getting linker errrors but my error is about "DLL"

I get

"The program can't start because DevIL.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"

I do not want the .dll. I linked the other libraries for a reason.
Or am I assuming wrong and DevIL will only work by me having to place this DLL in the system root?

Because my goal is to link DevIL without putting any DLLs in other places. I just figured I could use the the linker libraries like how you can with openGL.

If there's any good example let me know. I have also done some tutorials and a few examples but no luck. I keep getting this "DevIL.dll is missing" error window.

Comment: It looks like you're using an *import* library of a DLL. You need a *static* library, and likely have to change/add a `#define` so the header doesn't declare lib function as provided in a DLL but rather from a static lib. If this is possible it should be documented in the install, readme, or usage links of the library SDK you're using. A brief peek [**at the library website**](http://openil.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) and its documentation links suggests it is *not* possible to use this SDK without dynamic linking.

Comment: Put `DevIL.dll` into the same directory that contains your executable file.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK ,the DevIL distributions come with import libs only.What you are talking about is called  [static library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) which is compiled into your executable and therefore doesn't require DLL.I tried to search for static libs of DevIL but didn't find.So you have to build DevIL from sources to compile static version by yourself.